# (Object doesn't support #inspect) rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am facing (Object doesn't support #inspect) error while fetching the all rows through ActiveRecord .

In my rails Console : LevelFrameworkRule.all where LevelFrameworkRule is model class .

```
class LevelFrameworkRule < ActiveRecord::Base <br>
end
```

I already searched google but could not find the relevant solution to the problem. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you override initialize in your model? If yes  - add super(params) to it

Comment: Does your model code (or any related object) override #inspect? Have you checked for syntax errors?

Comment: same thing here. Used `gem 'jdbc-h2', platform: :jruby` I think h2 is the problem.